# Find the largest value of time

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.6

I am looking for the script which will search the largest time value from the mysql returned row.
Mysql returned row like:

```
(123, 'new', datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 2, 16, 6, 21))
(122, 'old', datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 3, 18, 08, 36))
(125, 'new', datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 13, 20, 18, 16))
```

i tried with:

```
value = 0
for row in rows:
  if row[2] > value:
    value = row
print value
```

if we print the row[2] value that will show like that

```
for row in rows:
 print row[2]

output: 2013-01-02 16:06:21
        2012-12-03 18:08:36
        2013-12-13 20:18:16
```

Comment: The question indicates that you have no knowledge about SQL otherwise you would know about SORT and LIMIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Anders Johansson** answers your question neatly.

However, you could also avoid the need to do this in Python to begin with, by simply requesting only that line of data.  A SQL statement like:

```sql
SELECT DateTime FROM MyTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Status IS 'new' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC, DateTime DESC LIMIT 1;
```

would achieve what you're trying to do, and give you only that one data point.

#### Update:

```sql
SELECT mydate FROM MyTable
WHERE type=4
ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'new', 'waited', 'old'), mydate DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a434c/2/0)

Comment: actually i want to fetch the value in such a way that if the status = new then find the maximum date value and return one row if status is not new take old and find the latest date and print the row.

Comment: @Surya Still better with a SQL statement, see update.
Also, you should really accept some answers.

Comment: your answers are really helpful for me.. thank you so much.. But some times status are not only new or old, it can be "waited" also. first i want to search for status=new and select the row according to the latest date if status is not new then go for status=waited and search for latest date if waited is also not there then go for status= old search for latest date and return one row

Comment: So why didn't you just write that in the first place?  This code does that also; it's all the same custom sorting concept.

Comment: I did like that:   SELECT mydate FROM MyTable
WHERE FIELD(status, 'new', 'waited', 'old') and type=4
ORDER BY mydate DESC
LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
print max(x[2] for x in rows)
```

Comment: How to print the max time value in the above case

Comment: Accept answers - otherwise nobody is interested in helping you.